# How do I insert 500,000 random values into a column in My SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

If I have a table named `page_info` and three columns `id INT, visitor_id INT, duration DEC(4,1)`, how do I add 500,000 random values for each column? For example, if I want 500,000 total rows, I want my `id` to be anywhere from 1-500, I want my `visitor_id` to be anywhere from 1-10,000, and I want my duration to be anywhere between 000.1-240.0.

Comment: Try looking into rand()

Answer (score 0):

Create a stored procedure, such as a:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE vId INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE vVis INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE vDur DECIMAL(4,1) DEFAULT 0.0;

    WHILE i < 500001 DO

        while vId = 0 do
            set vId = FLOOR(RAND() * 500);
        end while;

        while vVis = 0 do
            set vVis = FLOOR(RAND() * 10000);
        end while;

        while vDur = 0.0 do
            set vDur = RAND() * 240;
        end while;

        INSERT page_info (id, visitor_id, duration) VALUES( vId, vVis, vDur );
        SET i = i + 1;

        IF i < 500001 THEN
            set vId = 0;
            set vVis = 0;
            set vDur = 0.0;
        END IF;

    END WHILE;
END
```